# What is angular way to transform a table cell

Tags: angularjs

The problem is as follows. I have a directive which builds some table, and i use `ng-repeat` to construct table rows dynamicly. Each row has two buttons for editing and deleting accordingly. I look for action with `ng-click`, but how then transform a cell with static text into a cell with an input field in angular way? I know how to do it with jquery. I look around with `ng-switch`, but i can't get it works inside `ng-repeat` on a table cell as expected. My code:

**JS**

```
order.directive('orderLines',function($http,calculateTotalQtyService,$compile){

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope,element, attrs){

        $scope.editLine = function(line,order_id){
           // alert ('Edit'+line.id);
          some code here to perform transformation

        }
        $scope.deleteLine = function(idx){
            var line_to_delete = $scope.order.lines[idx]
            $http.post('/delete/line?id='+line_to_delete.id +'&order_id='+$scope.order.id).success(function(data){
                  $scope.order.lines.splice(idx,1);
                  $scope.order = data.ord;
                  $scope.order.customer = data.customer;
                  $scope.order.lines = data.lines;
                  var res = calculateTotalQtyService.set(data.lines);
                  $scope.total_kg = res[0];
                  $scope.total_piece = res[1];
            });

        }

    },
    templateUrl:'/assets/fragments/order/order_lines.html',
    replace: true
}
});
```

**and HTML**

```
    <div class="span12 fiche" id="lines">
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="order_lines">
        <thead class="header_lines">
        <th>S.N.</th>
        <th>Ref.</th>
        <th>Label</th>
        <th>Tva</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Unite</th>
        <th>Prix HT</th>
        <th>Total HT</th>
        <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-switch="lines.length">
        <tr id="no_record" ng-switch-when="0"><th colspan="9"  style="text-align: center" >No records</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="line in order.lines">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td class='line-ref'>{{line.product_ref}}</td>
            <td>{{line.label}}</td>
            <td class='line-tva'>{{line.tva}}</td>
            <td class='line-qty'>{{line.qty}}</td>
            <td class='line-unity'>{{line.unity}}</td>
            <td class='line-prix_ht'>{{line.prix_ht}}</td>
            <td>{{line.prix_ht*line.qty}}</td>
            <th class='control-buttons'>
                <button  class='btn editline' ng-click="editLine(line,order.id)"><i class='icon-edit'></i></button>
                <button class='btn deleteline' ng-click="deleteLine($index)"><i class='icon-trash'></i> </button>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

So html is a template, that i use in directive. How perform transformation ? with ng-switch? but how, or there are other solutions ? I want to avoid jquery if it's possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got it with a custom directive, inspired by @laut3rry. For those who would be interested this is my solution:

Directive:

order.directive('editable', function(){

```
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    replace : true,
    template: '<div><span ng-hide="editMode">{{line.qty}</span><input class="span1" ng-show="editMode" type="text" ng-model="line.qty"/></div>',

    link : function(scope, element, attrs){

    }
}
```

});

And in HTML, in my example it's for a qty cell only, that I need to change, but we can use it with any cell and with a little bit of modification, for example by passing cell value in the attribute of the directive and it can be universal:

```
<td class='line-qty'><editable></editable></td>
```

In my controller I initialize `$scope.editMode = false` the cell isn't editable by default and  then in the ng-click="editLine()" handler we change `$scope.editMode = true` and the cell transforms in to the input field. So directives and directives and once more directives.... :)

For those who is interested, here the link to the plunk [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/GCvxKhYEqdKPcXa411mE?p=preview)

Comment: any chance you could create a fiddle/plunk with this demo?

Comment: @FutuToad I'm apologise, may be a little bit late, but it's Christmas holidays yet :), I have updated my answer with a plunker link, hope this helps.